# How to fix 'unused arguments' error on nls model

Tags: r, function, arguments, curve-fitting

```
A <- c(100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600)
B <- c(60, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10)
data <- data.frame(A,B)

sample_plot <- function(A,B)
{
(w * ((x * A)^2) / (y/z)
}

control <- nls.control(maxiter = 1000)
sample_model <- nls(B, w, x, y, z), control = control, start = list(w = 62.2060, x = 0.0438, y = 0.9692, z = 0.8693))

plot(A, predict(sample_model), type = "1", col = "blue")
points(A, B, col = "red")
summary(sample_model)
```

Everytime I run the codes of the model, it provides an error about the unused arguments which states that "`Error in sample_model(B, w, x, y, z) : unused arguments (x, y, z)`", even though I provided values for x, y, and z. I also try to change the `sample_plot <- function(A,B)` into `sample_plot <- function(A,B,...)` but it doesn't work. Any help? Thank You.

Comment: you close the bracket after the z in the nls call which wont be correct. You also dont seem to supply a function.

Comment: @user20650. It should be like this? sample_model <- nls(B ~ sample_plot, w, x, y, z), control = control, start = list(w = 62.2060, x = 0.0438, y = 0.9692, z = 0.8693))

Comment: I don't know but taking a punt; define the relevant bits of `sample_plot`  as `sample_plot <- function(A, w, x, y, z)` and the `nls` call with `nls(B ~  sample_plot(A, w, x, y, z)` maybies?? But it would be good if you provided a full example with data.

Comment: ... you also have an extra bracket in your  sample_plot function

Comment: @user20650. I edited the post, I provided some data. Thank You.

Comment: Thanks. did you have any luck when trying  the suggestions in the above [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59502816/how-to-fix-unused-arguments-error-on-nls-model?noredirect=1#comment105178299_59502816)

Comment: I removed the extra bracket, yet there is still an 'unused arguments' error.

Comment: `sample_plot <- function(A, w, x, y, z){(w * (x * A)^2) / (y/z)}; nls(B ~  sample_plot(A, w, x, y, z), control = control, start = list(w = 62.2060, x = 0.0438, y = 0.9692, z = 0.869), data=data)` Your function does seem to be overparameterised -- you can reduce it

Comment: @user20650. An error occured in sample_plot which states that object 'z' not found. Should I remove z to reduce the parameters?

Comment: the way your function is written you could remove the x, y, and z parameters but this doesnt leave much wiggle room to fit the curve. If you dont have a definite predefined function(s) for your curve then nls may not be the write tool

Comment: Root of the problem is your model is incorrect for the example data provided.  Your model can simplify down to (constant)*A^2, in which case these is no possible answer of having A increase and generate a result where B decreases. As demonstrated running: `sample_plot(A, w = 62.2060, x = 0.0438, y = 0.9692, z = 0.8693)` , your starting values are not even close to feasible solution.

Comment: @Dave2e. How can I fix the problem? Should I create or use other equation(s) for the function of the model? Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @user20650 has pointed out the model is overparametized and cannot give any different predictions than the model B ~ w * A^2.  This is because all the other parameters can be absorbed into w.  Further, as @Dave2e has indicated such a model can't fit the data in any reasonable way.

Plotting the data, B seems linear in A so using `lm` should do and, in fact, gives a perfect fit as the residual sum of squares is effectively zero.

```
fm <- lm(B ~ A, data)
fm

## Call:
## lm(formula = B ~ A, data = data)
##
## Coefficients:
## (Intercept)            A  
##        70.0         -0.1  

deviance(fm) # residual sum of squares
## [1] 1.390367e-28

plot(B ~ A, data)
abline(fm)
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Gronthendieck. I review the set of data, the data.frame will fit an lm model, rather than nls mode. I change the set of data and also the equation of the function, yet it still don't work.

Comment: Here is the new set of data. A <- c(507.23, 206.32, 70.86, 432.76, 265.77, 81.23) B <- c(67.32, 43.78, 8.55, 31.41, 54.11, 6.89)

Comment: If you have a variety of short series to fit that don't look the same and you want to use the same parametric form but with different parameter values for each series fix k, e.g. fix k = 1 if linear is ok, k = 2 if quadratic polynomials seem sufficient or fix it at some other value if not, and use `o <- order(A); A <- A[o]; B <- B[o]; lm(B ~ poly(A, k))`